# c# ? conditional - how to save results from a method call?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to do something like this in c#, where we are trying to call a different method as a part of a conditional statement that uses the "?" operator?

**Sample Code**

```
   private bool myTenStepMethodVersion()
   {
     var stepPassed = false;
     stepPassed = StepOne(reportDate);  
     stepPassed = (stepPassed) ? StepTwo() : RecordTimeAndLogFailure(timer,reportDate,"Step2");
     stepPassed = (stepPassed) ? StepThree() : RecordTimeAndLogFailure(timer,reportDate,"Step3");
   etc.
   }

   private bool StepOne(DateTime someDate)
   {
   //do stuff
   return true;
   }

   private bool StepTwo()
   {
   //do stuff
   return true;
   }

   private bool RecordTimeAndLogFailure(timer,someDate)
   {
   //write to a log the step where we failed, timer and date. 
   }
```

The idea was to avoid having 10 different if / then combos for a 10 step process.

This type of an approach kinda works until:
a) step3 needs some data created by step 2?  aka.  I want to return something other than a bool?  I guess we can create private global variables in the class and have each step check it? is there another way?

b) After we run RecordTimeAndLogFailure(), we need to actually just exit the entire method.  How can we do that if we follow this type of an approach?

Overall, the goal is to make the code more readable.  The current code has multiple if / then statements and over 60 lines in the main method

Comment: For your first requirement, you could probably either use `out` parameters or assign a local variable within the condition (something like `stepPassed = (stepPassed) ? (twoOutput = StepTwo()) : RecordTimeAndLogFailure(timer,reportDate,"Step2");`). For your second requirement you could either do something similar, or you could probably just throw an exception that you catch later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Exceptions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/) for error handling come to mind immediately:

```
   class StepException : Exception {
     public string Step { get; }
     public StepException(string step) {
       this.Step = step;
     }
   }

   private bool myTenStepMethodVersion2()
   {
     try
     {
       stepOne(reportDate);
       var data = stepTwo();
       stepThree(data);
       // …
       return true;
     } catch (StepException ex) {
       RecordTimeAndLogFailure(timer, reportDate, ex.Step);
       return false;
     }
   }

   private void StepOne(DateTime reportDate)
   {
     if (error) { throw new StepException("Step2"); }
     // do stuff …
   }

   private StepTwoResult StepTwo()
   {
     var result = new StepTwoResult();
     // do stuff ...
     if (error) { throw new StepException("Step2"); }
     return result;
   }

   private RecordTimeAndLogFailure(timer,reportDate)
   {
     //write to serilog the step where we failed, timer and date. 
   }
```

Comment: StepOne doesn't throw an exception, and StepThree doesn't exist. You could also show that StepThree can return data.

Comment: @Lithis how do you know that StepOne doesn't throw an exception? "do stuff" can include throwing an exception :) Or not, who knows. It's just an illustrative example. The code is copied mostly verbatim from the Q.

Comment: That's true. I meant that it doesn't explicitly throw an exception like StepTwo does.

Comment: The truth is i want all methods to handle errors.  I love this answer.  Waiting for the 5 minutes to expire to accept.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this in c# the short way is to use a functional approach

```
    //Probably want the result of the pipleine to be somthing other  then an array  
//This will run all the steps and record faliers
Pipeline().Select(RunAndRecordFailure).ToArray();

//this will run untill first fails
Pipeline().TakeWhile(RunAndRecordFailure).ToArray();

static bool RunAndRecordFailure((string name, Func<bool> step) step) => step.step() ? true : RecordTimeAndLogFailure(step.name);

static IEnumerable<(string name, Func<bool> step)> Pipeline()
{
    yield return (nameof(Step1), () => Step1(DateTime.Now));
    yield return (nameof(Step2), Step2);
    yield return (nameof(Step3), Step3);
}

static bool Step1(DateTime dateTime) => true;
static bool Step2() => true;
static bool Step3() => true;

static bool RecordTimeAndLogFailure(string step) => false;
```

Or use a [state machine](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha)

Or maybe the best way use proper object-oriented patterns with a step interface and proper error handling.